# Fedora Login Incorrect when installing vm through qemu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, passwords, fedora

I am trying to boot fedora vm on Linux Test Pc from qemu. It actually shows the temporary password for first login. But when I try that password it is saying Login is Incorrect. I don't know why the password is showing incorrect although I entered the correct password.

I downloaded fedora cloud image from
https://mirror.genesisadaptive.com/fedora/linux/releases/36/Cloud/x86_64/images/

The command I used is
sudo virt-install --connect qemu:///system --name CXL-Test --memory 4096 --cpu host --vcpus 4 --os-variant fedora35 --import --graphics none --disk /var/lib/libvirt/images/CXL-Test.qcow2,format=qcow2,bus=virtio --cloud-init

The tutorial I am following is:
https://stevescargall.com/blog/2022/01/20/how-to-emulate-cxl-devices-using-kvm-and-qemu/#configure-the-guest-os-using-a-cloud-init-boot-strap-image

The console shows:

WARNING  Defaulting to --cloud-init root-password-generate=yes,disable=yes

Starting install...

Password for first root login is: gjxGCzxrSzkknlu4

Creating domain...
|    0 B  00:00:00

Running text console command: virsh --connect qemu:///system console CXL-Test

Connected to domain 'CXL-Test'

Fedora Linux 36 (Cloud Edition)

Kernel 5.17.5-300.fc36.x86_64 on an x86_64 (ttyS0)

fedora login: root

Password:
Login incorrect

Could you please resolve my issue? Thanks in advance.